# Can you put a logical test with a UDF inside a SUMIF?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to place a logical test inside of a SumIF formula. I was trying to do this without VBA, but maybe it needs to be.

I have attached a photo at the bottom of some sample data.

My code for cell B11 currently is:

```
=SUM((SUMIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()-1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))), indentlevel(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))=0, (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))))
```

Now I have created a UDF that counts the indent level of a cell. It is placed in a module and it works. If you were to type =indentlevel(A2) in a cell it would return the value of 2. So I know that part works.

I just can't get it to sum, only the rows that are NOT indented.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

[image: Sample Data]

Here is the code I was using to determine the indent level

```
Function indentlevel(Cell As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    indentlevel = Cell.indentlevel
End Function
```

Comment: Can you include your code for `indentlevel` so we can better answer this particular question?

Comment: Perhaps you could instead put a short list together of the "headings" (e.g. "New Tires", "Oil Change", etc.) Then you could just do a SUMIFS the value in col A *isn't* in that list, then sum up?  Edit: What exactly are you trying to SUM here?

Comment: Perhaps this is oversimplifying but what about using `SUM(B1:B10)/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B$1:INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1),--(indentlevel($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))=0))
```

This will only work if you UDF is set up to output arrays like this:

```
Function indentlevel(rng) As Variant()
Application.Volatile
Dim temp()
ReDim temp(0 To rng.Count - 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To rng.Count - 1
    temp(i) = rng(i + 1).indentlevel
Next i
 indentlevel = Application.Transpose(temp)
End Function
```

One Note:  The formatting of a cell, which indent is, will not fire the re-calculation of the cells, so one must hit F9 to force the recalc if only the indent changed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, works perfect. Thank you for the clarification of the refresh, For my application, it will work fine, but might cause someone else some problems.

Comment: Just a follow up to anyone else who stumbles across this. I removed the line ```Application.Volatile``` to keep Excel from constantly recalculating whenever I did something. It made it very difficult to step through other Macro's and troubleshoot. I added the line ```Application.CalculateFull``` (Ctrl+Alt+F9) at the end of my Macro and that makes the UDF fire and then everything works great. Using ```Application.Calculate``` (F9) will not make it fire.